# How to transform XML with XSL using Java

Tags: java, xml, transform, xslt

I am currently using the standard javax.xml.transform library to transform my XML to CSV using XSL.  My XSL file is large - at around 950 lines.  My XML files can be quite large also.

It was working fine in the prototype stage with a fraction of the XSL in place at around 50 lines or so.  Now in the 'final system' when it performs the transform it comes up with the error **Branch target offset too large for short**.

```
private String transformXML() {
    String formattedOutput = "";
    try {

        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();            
        Transformer transformer =
                tFactory.newTransformer( new StreamSource( xslFilename ) );

        StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream( xmlString.getBytes() ) );
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        transformer.transform( xmlSource, new StreamResult( baos ) );

        formattedOutput = baos.toString();

    } catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return formattedOutput;
}
```

I came across a few postings on this error but not too sure what to do.
Am I doing anything wrong code wise?
Are there any alternative 3rd Party transformers available that could do this?

Thanks,

Andez

Comment: Don't use `xmlString.getBytes()`, it will convert the string to bytes using the default platform encoding, which might not be the one you want, and thus your code is platform dependent. Instead use `new StreamSource(new StringReader( xmlString ) )`, or even more preferably, if `xmlString` was read from an input stream and converted to a string, just use the bytes from the stream instead of converting them to a string first, which probably also is platform dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a post on the net that mentioned apache XALAN.  So I added the jars to my project.  Everything has started working since even though I do not directly reference any XALAN classes in my code.  As far as I can tell it still should use the jaxax.xml classes.

Not too sure what is happening there.  But it is working.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Your code would stay the same. All you would need to do is set `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` to `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl` in the JVM's system properties.

Answer (score 3):

Use saxon. offtop: if you use the same stylesheet to transform many XML files, you might want to consider templates (pre-compiled stylesheets):

```
javax.xml.transform.Templates style = tFactory.newTemplates(xslSource);
style.newTransformer().transform(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Saxon, you can split up your large template into smaller templates.

> Template definitions contained in XSLT stylesheets are compiled by SAP
>   JVM's XSLT compiler "Xalan" into Java methods for faster execution of
>   transformations. Java bytecode branch instructions contained in these
>   Java methods are limited to 32K offsets. Large template definitions
>   can now lead to very large Java methods, where the branch offset would
>   need to be larger than 32K. Therefore these stylesheets cannot be
>   compiled to Java methods and therefore cannot be used for
>   transformations.

**Solution**

> Since each template definition of an XSLT stylesheet is compiled into
>   a separate Java method, using multiple smaller templates can be used
>   as solution. A very large template can be broken into multiple smaller
>   templates by using the "[call-template](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_call-template.asp)" element.

It is described in-depth in this article [Size limitation for XSLT stylesheets](http://www.stechno.net/sap-notes.html?view=sapnote&id=1273115).

Sidenote: I would only recommend this as a **last resort** if saxon is not available, as this requires quite a few changes to your xsl file.