# DOM parser, why do I get just one child of an element?

Tags: java, xml, dom, nodes

my question is "DOM parser, why do I get just one child of an element?"

I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658626/get-the-all-the-children-of-a-parent-node-in-xml-in-android-dom-parser) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280814/parsing-through-dom-get-all-children-and-values) one, but I do not get the point.

What I'm trying to do is the following:

I have an XML file (see the extract below) :

```
<POITEM>
   <item>
      <PO_ITEM>00010</PO_ITEM>
      <SHORT_TEXT>ITEM_A</SHORT_TEXT>
      <MATL_GROUP>20010102</MATL_GROUP>
      <AGREEMENT>4600010076</AGREEMENT>
      <AGMT_ITEM>00010</AGMT_ITEM>
      <HL_ITEM>00000</HL_ITEM>
      <NET_PRICE>1.000000000</NET_PRICE>
      <QUANTITY>1.000</QUANTITY>
      <PO_UNIT>EA</PO_UNIT>
   </item>
   <item>
      <PO_ITEM>00020</PO_ITEM>
      <SHORT_TEXT>ITEM_B</SHORT_TEXT>
      <MATL_GROUP>20010102</MATL_GROUP>
      <AGREEMENT>4600010080</AGREEMENT>
      <AGMT_ITEM>00020</AGMT_ITEM>
      <HL_ITEM>00000</HL_ITEM
      <NET_PRICE>5.000000000</NET_PRICE>
      <QUANTITY>5.000</QUANTITY>
      <PO_UNIT>EA</PO_UNIT>
   </item>
</POITEM>
```

I only want to extract `<PO_ITEM>, <SHORT_TEXT>, <MATL_GROUP>, <NET_PRICE>, <QUANTITY>` and `<PO_UNIT>` and write it into another, smaller XML file.

So this is my code:

```
nodes = dcmt.getElementsByTagName("POITEM");

Element rootElement2 = doc1.createElement("PO_POSITIONS");
rootElement1.appendChild(rootElement2);

Element details2 = doc1.createElement("PO_DETAILS");
rootElement2.appendChild(details2);

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element = (Element) node;

        Element position = doc1.createElement("position");
        details2.appendChild(position);

        Element poItm = doc1.createElement("PO_ITEM");
        poItm.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(getValue("PO_ITEM", element)));
        position.appendChild(poItm);

        Element matlGrp = doc1.createElement("MATL_GROUP");
        matlGrp.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(getValue("MATL_GROUP",element)));
        position.appendChild(matlGrp);

        Element poUnit = doc1.createElement("PO_UNIT");
        poUnit.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(getValue("PO_UNIT",element)));
        position.appendChild(poUnit);

        Element netPrice = doc1.createElement("NET_PRICE");
        netPrice.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(getValue("NET_PRICE",element)));
        position.appendChild(netPrice);

        Element shortTxt = doc1.createElement("SHORT_TEXT");
        shortTxt.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(getValue("SHORT_TEXT",element)));
        position.appendChild(shortTxt);

        //Element matl = doc2.createElement("MATERIAL");
        //matl.appendChild(doc2.createTextNode(getValue("MATERIAL",element)));
        //details2.appendChild(matl);

        Element qnty = doc1.createElement("QUANTITY");
        qnty.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(getValue("QUANTITY",element)));
        position.appendChild(qnty);

        /*Element preqNr = doc1.createElement("PREQ_NO");
          preqNr.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(getValue("PREQ_NO",element)));
          details2.appendChild(preqNr); */
    }
}
```

So far so good, I'm getting a new XML File, but it only holds the first entry, so as i understand it, by the `nodes = dcmt.getElementsByTagName("POITEM");` gets into the first  `<item>` until the first `</item>` and then gets out of the loop. So how do I manage step into the next item? Do I need to create some kind of loop, to access the next `<item>` ?
By the way, changing the structure of the XML file is no option, since I get the file from an interface.
Or do I make a mistake while writing the new XML file?

The output looks like this:

```
<PO_POSITIONS>
  <PO_DETAILS>
    <position>
      <PO_ITEM>00010</PO_ITEM>
      <MATL_GROUP>20010102</MATL_GROUP>
      <PO_UNIT>EA</PO_UNIT>
      <NET_PRICE>1.00000000</NET_PRICE>
      <SHORT_TEXT>ITEM_A</SHORT_TEXT>
      <QUANTITY>1.000</QUANTITY>
    </position>
  </PO_DETAILS>
</PO_POSITIONS>
```

Comment: Since your XML and the code don't match, it is difficult to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @Stephen C Okay, Why? My problem is, that I only get back the attributes of the first `<item>`. I see the problem in the  **nodes = dcmt.getElementsByTagName("POITEM")** part. And I get a XML file out of it, which contains the first `<item>`, but not the second, third an so on.

Comment: You don't get it.  The XML doesn't contain an element called "POITEM" ... so the program cannot possibly behave as you describe.  Please provide a *proper* SSCCE and *proper* input, not some bowdlerised hacked-around stuff that doesn't make sense.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: Oh, sorry. i see my mistake now. okay, I will provide an extract from the actual XML File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse it yourself, it's kind of a pain. When I did xml way back when, we used to use stylesheets to do these kinds of transformations. Something like this post: [How to transform XML with XSL using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095287/how-to-transform-xml-with-xsl-using-java)

If that's not an option, then to do it by hand (I omitted the new document construction, but you can see where it goes):

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XMLTest { 
    @Test
    public void testXmlParsing() throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("/Users/aakture/Documents/workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE/smartfox/branches/trunk/java/gelato/src/test/resources/sample.xml").getAbsolutePath());
        Node poItem = doc.getElementsByTagName("POITEM").item(0);
        NodeList poItemChildren = poItem.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < poItemChildren.getLength(); i++) {
            Node item = poItemChildren.item(i);
            NodeList itemChildren = item.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < itemChildren.getLength(); j++) {
                Node itemChild = itemChildren.item(j);
                if("PO_ITEM".equals(itemChild.getNodeName())) {
                    System.out.println("found PO_ITEM: " +     itemChild.getTextContent());
                }
                if("MATL_GROUP".equals(itemChild.getNodeName())) {
                    System.out.println("found MATL_GROUP: " + itemChild.getTextContent());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Helped me a lot, now everything is working just fine. I got along with your second option.

Comment: np, ya, it's not so bad by hand I guess.