# sed to edit only part of a file with regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a file named test.txt with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<test time="60" id="01">
<java.lang.String value="cat"/><java.lang.String value="dog"/>
<java.lang.String value="mouse"/>
<java.lang.String value="cow"/>
</test>
```

What I  would like to do is that , i want to edit the file so that when i get something like , `<java.lang.String value="something"/>` i will change that part to `<animal>something</animal>`

So for previous example , after applying a script with `sed/awk/grep` command the file content will be changed to or a new file will be created like following:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <test time="60" id="01">
    <animal>cat</animal><animal>dog</animal>
    <animal>mouse</animal>
    <animal>cow</animal>
    </test>
```

I tried to extract that particular part using following command :

```
$less test.txt | grep -Po 'java.lang.String value="\K[^"]*' | awk -F: '{print "<animal>" $1 "</animal>"}'
```

The output gives me the changed part, but I want this changed part along with the rest of the file unchanged  :

```
<animal>cat</animal>
<animal>dog</animal>
<animal>mouse</animal>
<animal>cow</animal>
```

I am new to scripting , I don't know how to write the complete output in a file .

Comment: please, try to use the right tool for the right task. Transforming an XML document shall be done using XSL transformations, not sed/grep/etc.. There are standard tools for that and it can check your input file as it's giving you the right result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -r 's#<java.lang.String value="([^"]*)"/>#<animal>\1</animal>#g' test.txt
```

And you should not do `XML` transformations with regular expressions...

**EDIT about how it works**

By default `sed` uses "basic regular expressions", where many special characters have to be prefixed with `\`. `-r` flag switches to "extended regular expressions" where the syntax is less cumbersome. See [OpenGroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) for details.

By default `sed` prints output as-is unless commands modify it. The replacement command is like `s#search_regexp#replacement#flags`. The delimiter can be anything like `/`, `#`, or `,`. I choose `#` so it doesn't clash with the `\` character in `XML`.

Then we match things like `<java.lang.String value="anything_except_quotes"/>`. The part that we want to reuse has parenthesis, it's called a matching group. In the replacement we refer to the thing we captured inside the matching group by `\1`.

`g` flag makes `sed` replace all occurences of the search pattern, not only the first one.

Comment: Thanks , Can you please explain a bit how this is giving the proper output ? I am not good at sed

Answer (score 2):

ok some problems with your command:

```
less test.txt | grep -Po 'java.lang.String value="\K[^"]*' | awk -F: '{print "<animal>" $1 "</animal>"}'
```

to begin with, there's a useless use of `less`, grep can take a file as a parameter:

```
grep -Po 'java.lang.String value="\K[^"]*' test.txt | awk -F: '{print "<animal>" $1 "</animal>"}'
```

then you're using `grep` to select lines that matches a string, so basically, your sequence of commands is *explicitely* keeping only the lines that have the `java.lang...` string, taking everything else out... A simpler solution would be to use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's,<java.lang.String value="([^"]*)"\s*/>,<animal>\1</animal>,g' test.txt
```

which uses the substitution syntax of sed to replace the match, while extracting what's in the parenthesis `(` and `)` as `\1` in the right part. The `[^"]` part is for matching everything that is not a `"` character, and the `*` operator is to apply the match 0 or more times. The `\s` is to match a space, `*`, 0 or more times.

A regex is an automaton that uses states and transitions to match a given string. Here's a visual of how the regex works:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[demo of the regex on an example](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vyTx3ra9aKg92-_k)

Though in your particular case that simple regex works out, keep in mind that this is only a *hack*. You should instead use an XML parser and replace the nodes to match your needs, using XSLT/XSLFO that are tools designed to transform an XML into another one (or something else).

To do that, you could use a tool such as `xsltproc` and look at [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484912/) for an example that transforms all `foo` nodes into `bar` nodes in an XML tree, here's how to do it:

test.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Identity Template. This will copy everything as-is.-->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Change "java.lang.String" element to "animal" element.-->
  <xsl:template match="java.lang.String">
    <animal>
      <!-- get the attribute 'value' of java.lang.String -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </animal>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

run:

```
xsltproc test.xsl test.xml
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test time="60" id="01">
  <animal value="cat"/>
  <animal value="dog"/>
  <animal value="mouse"/>
  <animal value="cow"/>
</test>
```

and by the way, given your XML, it looks like it has been generated by Java, and there's multiple ways to apply that XSL from [within your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095287/how-to-transform-xml-with-xsl-using-java), even before you need to handle it using command line tools.

Comment: Does not work with OP's example because lacking the 'g' flag in your `sed`.

Comment: Your answer becomes a sort of a thesis on `XML` manipulation. +1 for the exhaustive explanation.

Comment: uhuh... I don't agree this is a thesis on XML ;-) I'm just making a point on using the right tools for the right tasks.